# Update key in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been going through the docs, but I don't see a way to update a value at a specific key (while keeping the rest). Is the only way to achieve this is to fetch the existing data and overwrite it using set()?

I have something like this:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/products/${productKey}`)
    .set({category: name});
```

where products have many other key-value pairs, and using set() overwrites the entire object, which is not what I want in this case.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the section [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields):

> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the `update()` method.

In your snippet that would be:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/products/${productKey}`)
  .update({category: name});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. I don't know how I missed that whole section in the documentation. It must have been late.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Frank.